# Hyperlink with a cell link

Tags: excel, ms-office

If you want to get data from a different workbook's cell you do [something like this:](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-and-manage-links-to-other-workbooks-HA001054812.aspx)

```
='FilePath\[FileName]Worksheet'!ColumnRow
```

When you want to create a hyperlink to another workbook you do something like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("[FilePath\FileName]Worksheet!ColumnRow", FriendlyName)
```

Now how do you get `FriendlyName` to be a reference to the external cell `='FilePath\[FileName]Worksheet'!ColumnRow`?

Example:
I have two Excel documents.

1. C:\Fish\FTypes.xlsx

   - Has a worksheet named **Summary**
2. C:\Birds\BTypes.xlsx

In `FTypes.xlsx` I have cell **B:36** with some data in it. In `BTypes.xlsx` I want the cell **G:55** to be a hyperlink to `FTypes.xlsx` **B:36** cell. Also, as the "FirendlyName" for `BTypes.xlsx` **G:55** cell, I want it to be the data from `FTypes.xlsx` **B:36** cell. How would I go about doing that? Here is my attempt at it:

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\Fish\FTypes.xlsx]Summary!B36",'C:\Fish\[FTypes.xlsx]Summary!B36')
```

That one says "We found a problem with this formula. ..." I also tried:

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\Fish\FTypes.xlsx]Summary!B36","'C:\Fish\[FTypes.xlsx]Summary!B36'")
```

That on just puts **'C:\Fish[FTypes.xlsx]Summary!B36'** in the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (note at my closing `'` after `Summary`):

```
=HYPERLINK('C:\Fish\[FTypes.xlsx]Summary'!B36,'C:\Fish\[FTypes.xlsx]Summary'!B36)
```